# Asynchronous loading of content into div echoed in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, asynchronous

I have a button that loads a list of artists from a MySQL server, each artist has a link related to it and a div for adding content. the link fetches song data relating to that artist. I want to load the song data asynchronously but i am having trouble working out how to do it due to the URL encoding and the div being dynamically produced with PHP.

my page.

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>BadNoise</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="Artist.php" method="post"> 
            <fieldset> 
                <p> <input type="submit" value=" Search Our Artists" /> </p> 
            </fieldset> 
        </form> 

        <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","ee2800","secret","ee2800");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM artist LIMIT 10");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

echo " <h2>List of BadNoise Artists</h2>
    <table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Artist Number</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Search Songs</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td> <a href="test4.php?name='. urlencode($row['ArtistNumber']).'">Search Songs</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<td><div id=" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "></div></td>";

}

echo "</table>";

$results->close();
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my file for getting song info.

```
    <?php

$row = $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['name'];

$dbs = new mysqli("localhost", "ee2800", "secret", "ee2800");

$results = $dbs->query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE ArtistNumber = {$_GET['name']};");

$rows = array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
  {
    $rows[] = $r;
  }

  echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

edit!

this was my attempt with ajax...

```
   $("#dynamic").click(function() {

   $.getJSON( "test4.php", function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
               $("#dynamic").append("<p>"+value.Title+"</p>");

               return false;
            });
        });


});
```

I changed the div id to dynamic and replaced the URL with a #.
I know this is not quite right, as it worked on a test page that did not url encode and used a html div rather than a div echoed with php. I'm not sure how I would pass the query to the query for getting song data and then use the ajax function together.

Comment: To load the content asynchronously you'd need to use either ajax or a websocket, please post what you attempted so far

Comment: The problem i have is how do I send the ArtistNumber that I originally url encoded, if i need to replace the url with a #.

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your while loop

```
echo '<td> <a href="#'.urlencode($row['ArtistNumber']).'">Search Songs</a></td>';
```

and  for your js

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
      var qryStr = '?name='+ window.location.hash.split('#')[1]
     $.getJSON( "test4.php"+qryStr, function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
               $("#dynamic").append("<p>"+value.Title+"</p>");


            });
        });
  return false;

});
```

Comment: problem would be the div's id is not "dynamic" the ID is the artist number.

echo "<td><div id=" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "></div></td>";

Comment: sorry I'm confusing myself! and I'm sure you! the div that i wish the data to go into has the same ID as the artist number that is being passed. am i making sense??

Comment: is there a way of identifying the div in js?

Comment: you would generally have some fixed part of the id and some dynamic part and then target with jQuery like `var name=window.location.hash.split('#')[1]; $("#dynamic"+name);` and in the php you'd echo out `"<div id='dynamic{$row[ArtistNumber]}'></div>"`